# Points on my ggplot graphs are not appearing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a volcano plot in R. Whenever I do, the axis (in the correct scale) appears with no points plotted. I have checked and using `dev.off()` doesn't fix the problem.

The outcome when I try to plot a volcano plot

```r
ggplot(data = CvsC.IL33, aes(x = logFC, y = -log10(PValue)))
```

[image: outcome]

It can plot some graphs and doesn't seem to be an issue with the `ggplot2` package

```r
qplot(1:10, 1:10)
```

[image: outcome2]

Comment: Your ggplot code doesn't add a geom.

Comment: Try add `+ geom_point()`?

Comment: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_point.html

Answer (score 0):

You should add `geom_point` after your `ggplot()` call. Here a reproducible example like described at this [site](https://biocorecrg.github.io/CRG_RIntroduction/volcano-plots.html):

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=de, aes(x=log2FoldChange, y=pvalue)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see, the points are now shown. I would recommend you check the link above and maybe have a look at this [book](https://ggplot2-book.org) about `ggplot2`.